# Why is it that many rescues charge more for adoptions than I could get a puppy for from a breeder?

Tags: adoption, shelter

I often see ads on Facebook and Craigslist for mixed breed puppies in the $50-100 range but it seems most rescues have fees that are 200+.  I would think that a rescue organization would want to save more animals, but when they charge more, isn't that self-defeating?

So why do they charge so much more?

Comment: Those "breeders" are generally disreputable "puppy mills," who put very little into the care and treatment of their animals, resulting in "breeding stock" that is effectively being tortured to churn out "cute puppies" they can sell. They're very much "quantity over quality," and the conditions of the "breeder" and the dogs kept there are horrific.

Answer (score 9):

Usually the rescue organisation's fees include the cost of spaying or neutering, vaccinations, microchip, and perhaps more. For example, here's what the adoption costs for the [ASPCA adoption centre in Manhattan](http://www.aspca.org/adoptionsteps) include:

> The ASPCA Adoption Center offers you and your new animal companion the
>   following:
>
> Benefits
>
> ```
> A leash and collar or cardboard pet carrier to help you bring your new
> companion animal home.
> Spay/neuter surgery, up-to-date vaccinations, registered microchip, 
> heartworm testing, FeLV/FIV testing for cats and an
> overview of your pet's medical care.
> A certificate for free follow-up veterinary care and medical support at
> the ASPCA Animal Hospital (valid for 14 days after adoption).
> Literature and information about animal behavior and what to expect
> from your new pet.
> A collar with personalized identification tag.
> ```

Sometimes the cost will include pet insurance for a few weeks or months. And if you want to use your own vet for spaying, neutering, or vaccinations, some shelters might rebate that part of the cost when you present a receipt from your vet. Check around.

So if you are adopting a kitten or puppy, be sure to factor in the cost of spaying or neutering, vaccinations, microchipping, etc. before you compare prices.

Another thing to consider: In my experience, rescue organisations are very good at matching you with the pet that's best for you (in terms of temperament, behaviour, activity level, etc.). They have a variety of animals, and they have an incentive to make sure that you're happy with the pet that you get.

Also, consider that part of the adoption cost that you pay a shelter helps to keep that shelter running.

Comment: You might update this answer to identify the costs associated with the extras included in the rescue animal.  In my experience it is cheaper to get a vet from the shelter than to get a pet for free and have to pay separately for all the needs.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Indeed; shelters often have vets working for free (as a public service) or at least a steep discount (due to economy of scale).